# B spline - Partition of unity

Tags: spline

I need the Laplace form of the second order B splines over logarithmically-spaced knot.

I have read a paper in which it is mentioned that ;

" Heaviside function can be represented as the sum of all b-splines with indices from negative to positive infinity which is called partition of unity property ".

Please look at the  image attached ;

[Zero-th first and second order B-spline with index zero](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ts7gg.png)

How can I write for example the **second order B-spline with index 2,3** in terms of **Heaviside function** ?

I want to have the Laplace form of second order b-spline with indices from 0 to 4 which can be obtained easily if I can write B-spline with higher indices in terms of Heaviside function.

If you know any reference in this regards please introduce me.

Many thanks in advance ,
Ehsan